# How to customize the DataTemplate of ListViewItem when bound to collection

Tags: .net, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, uwp

I am having trouble customizing the `ListViewItems`. The listview is bound to an `ObservableCollection` in the ViewModel and I don't have any issues with the binding without the DataTemplate of ListViewItem set. But if the ItemTemplate is set I get the following exception:

> Message = "Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF
> (E_UNEXPECTED))"

On exploring about this exception this seems to occur for a variety of reasons and I am not able to find the cause.

Here is the View snippet:

```
<ListView
    Margin="12"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
    SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedFile, Mode=TwoWay}"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Files}"
    SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="vms:FileViewModel">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="File Name" Margin="5"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I tried converting the DataTemplate into a StaticResource also to no avail. And the ViewModel snippet is:

```
public ObservableCollection<FileViewModel> Files { get; } = new ObservableCollection<FileViewModel>();

public async Task InitAsync()
{
    store = new PersistedStore();
    await store.InitAsync();

    foreach (var model in await store.GetAllAsync())
    {
        Files.Add(new FileViewModel(model.Id, model.OriginalPath, model.ConvertedTypes, model.FileSize));
    }
}
```

Using breakpoints I was also able to ensure that the exception does not occur during the addition of files to the list. It happens immediately after the `InitAsync()`. Tried changing all to non-async methods just to identify the issue and same case.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: I added some code myself based on your code trying to reproduce this issue. The reason I found is that you are trying to set the `Name` for the `DisplayMemberPath` property. But the `FileViewModel` does not have such a `Name` Property. After removing it, the code could run correctly. Since your code is not complete, I'm not 100% sure this is the reason. If this is not the reason of your scenario, maybe you could consider sharing the full code of your `ViewModel` or share a [mcve] with us

Comment: I did come to the same conclusion @RoyLi-MSFT. Your guess is correct, but not because the `FileViewModel` not having the prop `Name`, it does have it. I am not sure about the exact reason why it failed, but the engine doesn't let me set both the DisplayMemberPath and the DataTemplate. Some kind of collision or ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the `DisplayMemberPath` property. It makes sense that the `DisplayMemberPath` and the `datatemplate` are in conflict. When you set the `DisplayMemberPath`, the ListView is supposed to sets the name or path of the property that is displayed for each data item. It uses the default ListViewItem. But setting the DataTemplate will change the this.

So I will say that you can't set the `DisplayMemberPath` property and the `DataTemplate` at the same time. It will be better to just use the `DataTemplate` to show the property you want.

Answer (score 0):

For customization DataTemplate  you can use inside it ListViewItem

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="vms:FileViewModel">
     <ListViewItem Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}">
         <TextBlock Text="File Name" Margin="5"/>
     </ListViewItem>
</DataTemplate>
```

You can assign to **Style** property **ListViewItemStyle** and customize it.

**Example** ListViewItemStyle`

```
<Style x:Key="CoffeeListStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="140" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="60" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" 
                                          Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" />
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```